# Unable to get a valid pathname from python os.path.abspath

Tags: python, windows, path

I have the following string containing absolute directory of a file.

```
'D:\Sample\Project\testXcl\data.xlsx'
```

On passing this into os.path.abspath, I am getting the following result:

```
'D:\\Sample\\Project\testXcl\\data.xlsx'
```

This happens because TestXcl folder name is read as \t. 
Wrong path/error also appears if any file/folder name is starting with n, a, b, f, r, v, x.

Is there any other method to rectify this, or should I go about replacing the string with correct file delimiters ?

Comment: +1 for researching spirit: you actually found the list of the escapable symbols :)

Answer (score 6):

When you specify the path name, either escape the backslashes or use a [raw string literal](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
p = 'D:\\Sample\\Project\\testXcl\\data.xlsx'
p = r'D:\Sample\Project\testXcl\data.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a raw string literal instead.

```
filename = r'D:\Sample\Project\testXcl\data.xlsx'
```