# How to make os.path.abspath(file) correct for folders beginning with "t"

Tags: python, python-2.7, path

I often use `os.path.abspath(file)` on a file address entered via the command line to sanitize it before I handle the file.

That means; performing the following:

```
outputPath = 'c:\Users\JEHOSHAPHAKSHAY\Desktop'
os.path.abspath(outputPath)
```

gives the following output:

```
'c:\\Users\\JEHOSHAPHAKSHAY\\Desktop'
```

This is in the hope that the code is more robust on different platforms and for different kinds of user inputs.

Recently I ran into an issue where this approach doesn't work as expected for a path that has one of the folders beginning with the letter **t**

That means; performing the following:

```
outputPath = 'c:\Users\JEHOSHAPHAKSHAY\Desktop\temp'
os.path.abspath(outputPath)
```

gives the following output:

```
'c:\\Users\\JEHOSHAPHAKSHAY\\Desktop\temp'
```

How do I get this to give me the correct path -

```
'c:\\Users\\JEHOSHAPHAKSHAY\\Desktop\\temp'
```

without doing a find and replace as that is not elegant?

Additionally, I don't mind using a raw string literal as long as I can prefix an existing string with a raw string literal.

Comment: Is this only a problem with directory names starting with `t`? Have you tested with directory names starting with `n`, for example? Might be a string-escaping issue (e.g. `\t` resolves to a tab character after the preceding slash isn't escaped)

Comment: For a string literal, `'\t'` is interpreted as the TAB character. Whenever writing strings, never leave unescaped `\ `s. Always double them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `os.path.abspath(file)` parses a string, it first looks at `\{char}` to see if it's a special escaped character, and only then if it isn't one, does it treat it like a normal part of a path.

You need to treat your path as a raw string by adding `r"...."` to get the desired output:

```
path = r'c:\Users\JEHOSHAPHAKSHAY\Desktop\temp'
os.path.abspath(path)
>> 'c:\\Users\\JEHOSHAPHAKSHAY\\Desktop\\temp'
```

Basically, by saying making it a raw string you tell the interpeter to ignore special escaped characters and just look at each char as exactly that - just a character.

You can see this succinctly in @phihag's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340546/unable-to-get-a-valid-pathname-from-python-os-path-abspath)

Comment: That does work for me. Although it opens a whole new can of worms in that I already have a string and now need to convert it "raw" which this question asks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707338/print-raw-string-from-variable-not-getting-the-answers. It doesn't look like that is easy to do for an existing string.

Comment: it looks like maybe `stringVar.encode('string-escape')` might solve that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428117/casting-raw-strings-python

Comment: although actually then it will escape the other preceding \'s too. hmmm.... let me think on that